# Is it possible to set DateTimeOffset to a SAME offset for all the Silverlight clients?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datetime, datetimeoffset

I use DateTimeOffset for the date/time values.

And what I want to achieve is, for all the clients who load their page to run a  SilverLight app., I want them to see the Dates according to a specific zone, for example Tokyo time.

So no conversion to their LocalTime will occur.

Is it possible to configure that for all the Silverlight clients they will see the DateTimeOffsets as for example, UTC + Offset of Tokyo ? Not as their local time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always returns Tokyo time

```
DateTimeOffset tokyoTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(9));
```

For DateTime you can use this:

```
DateTime tokyoTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a simliar problem, the solution I found was not to mark the date or DateTimeOffset property/fields as datamembers, but rather to create an additional string property that is the datamember and perform a string conversion in the getter/setter functions